# Rupee symbol is getting converted into some other symbol when it's displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this website built with Angular and Bootstrap. I am loading symbols from API. API has rupee symbol "₹". When its getting displayed on browser its displayed as something else entirely.

[image]

I tried to inspected from Developer tools it's again correct "₹" symbol.

```
<strong>₹</strong>
```

When displayed it's something different. Can't figure out why. Any idea?

Comment: Can you please post the API details?

Comment: What font are you displaying the symbol in? (sometimes, the glyphs can get messed up if you're using a font converted to web or a non-websafe font face)

Comment: Make sure the JSON is being served as UTF-8.

Comment: Also, FYI thats a Russian Ruble character: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20bd/index.htm

Comment: json should be served as UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have used web-fonts then check if those fonts support symbol. You can change font for that particular tag. My suggestion would be adding a class and use `font-family:Arial;` or make sure you use fonts that supports whatever symbol you use.

```
<strong class="currency">₹</strong>
```

Comment: I think you mean `font-family:Arial;` (note spelling of `Arial`)

Comment: silly.. why couldn't I think of this before? it Worked. thanks @Niraj.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `&#8377;` **HTML** entity to display the Rupee icon (₹).

```
<span style='font-family:Arial;'>&#8377;</span>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Backend is not returning &#8377. so can't use this.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&#8377;`
It will work.

```
<strong>&#8377;</strong>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Html entity

```
<label>&#8377; </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you specified your charset as "UTF-8" in your index.html as follows:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: I tried this and turns out issue was not related to this.